# Why datepicker calendar will not giving the assigned value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Here in the html I'm assigning the date to the text field but the calendar of the datepicker will not pick that assigned value it will show always me the current date.

Assigning the value to the text field Using jQuery:-

```js
 $('#datepicker').val("06-10-2018");
 
 
 $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      numberOfMonths: 2,
         onSelect: function(selected) {
            $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
         }
    });
  } );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

How will change the current value of calendar according the assigning of the value to the text field. Can anybody will help me for this. Thank you.

Comment: problem:- this date will show by the calendar as default and past dates will be disabled. @pedram

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize the `datepicker` first then set default value like this:

```js
var myDate = "06/10/2018";

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  minDate: myDate
}).datepicker("setDate", myDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Comment: how to disable the past date from the fiilled

Comment: @vikaskumar disable past date before `06/10/2018` ?

Comment: @vikaskumar use `minDate` set it to that value like: `minDate: myDate `

Comment: There is lot of change in this code actually @pedram in my jQuery code the dates are dynamically produce. Is it working for them

Comment: @vikaskumar It should work, no matter. Also you can set `minDate: 0`

Comment: will we discuss it in the chat room

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171819/discussion-between-pedram-and-vikas-kumar).

Comment: are you there or not?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to set value of the input field and update calender. Then you should use update option of bootstrap-datepicker.

```
$('#datepicker').val("06-10-2018");
$('#datepicker').datepicker("update");
```